# Brand new Eclipse plugin project riddled with errors

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have a brand new installation of the 2018‑12 R "Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java Developers", and am attempting to go through an Eclipse Plugin development tutorial (eg. https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipsePlugin/article.html) While I can create a plugin project, I'm immediately confronted with:

- NullPointerException at org.eclipse.pde.internal.core.plugin.WorkspaceExtensionsModel.getInstallLocation(WorkspaceExtensionsModel.java:79) on every view change
- Unresolved imports for everything org.eclipse (and javax.inject) (source file)
- Unknown extension point (plugin.xml)
- Unresolved bundle for every single entry (MANIFEST.MF)

I find it hard to believe that Eclipse plugin development is in such a sorry state, so I must be missing some feature. What do I need to look for?

Comment: The _Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java Developers_ is not for plug-in development. Use one of the following IDE packages instead: the _Eclipse IDE for Eclipse Committers_ or the _Eclipse IDE for RCP and RAP Developers_. If a bundle cannot be resolved, it is missing in the target platform. And bundles missing in the target platform cause unresolved imports and unknown extension points. In general, you can assume that all tools where dogfooding is used are in good condition and almost all non corner case issues are caused by incorrect use.

Comment: Thanks @howlger, that was it. I had assumed that the "and more" in the description for the "IDE for Enterprise Java Developers" would include plugin development, esp. as the plugin-project was available from the "New" menu. Using the "IDE for RCP and RAP Developers" gives me a project without any errors. (If you care to move your comment to an answer, I'll mark it as accepted)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ***Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java*** Developers is **not for plug-in development**.

Use one of the following IDE packages instead:

- the *Eclipse IDE **for Eclipse Committers*** or
- the *Eclipse IDE for **RCP and RAP** Developers*.

If a bundle cannot be resolved in `MANIFEST.MF`, it is missing in the target platform (see *Window > Preferences: Plug-in Development > Target Platform*). And bundles missing in the target platform cause unresolved imports and unknown extension points.